# ant build failed in ubuntu server 16.04, can not find symbol javax.servlet package

Tags: linux, tomcat, ant

Using eclipse in windows i generated build.xml file application. the build.xml, web content and src files are copied to my ubuntu server 16.04 box and started building using ANT.
but i am getting build fail error

```
 [javac] /home/reddy/repo_reddy/src/com/taf/common/GlobalExceptionHandler.java:7: error: package javax.servlet does not exist
```

i have open jdk 1.8 installed in my ubuntu 16.04 server

Comment: Are you sure you have Java EE (and not SE) installed?

Comment: Hey Mureinik, thanks for the replay. i don't know whether it is java SE or EE. i have installed open jdk 1.7 using apt-get install command. if it is not java EE then tell me how to install java EE please